# Adding 5-digit, right-aligned, zero-filled, one-based line numbers to lines within an existing file

Tags: python

I need to copy a file, add 5-digit line numbers to the beginning of each line, and save the output to a new file. This is what I currently have:

```
infile = open ('movies.txt', 'r')
outfile = open ('newFile.txt' , 'w')

text = infile.read()
outfile.write(text)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

I think that I need to use append, but I am not sure how to do it correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: You can read line by line using `for line in infile:`. I don't know what number you want to add but lets say its always 42. Then `outfile.write("{} {}".format(42, line)`.

Comment: Not a python answer, but does what you need: `nl -w5 -nrz -ba movies.txt > newFile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add line numbers to an existing file and save it to another file, you can open both input and output files, then use `enumerate` on the input file within a `for` loop to loop through line indices and line strings, writing each line index and line string to the output file, like so:

```
with open("movies.txt", "r") as in_file, open("movies_w_idx.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for idx, line in enumerate(in_file, start=1):
        out_file.write("{0:0>5} {1}\n".format(idx, line))
```

With this script, each line will start with a 5-digit, right-aligned, zero-filled, one-based line number. If you're getting excess line spaces, remove the `\n`.

Comment: I should have been more specific in my original post. It has to be a 5 digit number, so I cant use    enumerate.

Comment: @moparjoe95 Can you elaborate on what you mean by that exactly? Do you mean something like `00001`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean

Comment: @moparjoe95 Please see the updated answer. That should do it. I also made the indices one-based. Let me know if it works.

Comment: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) has an optional argument "start" which defaults to 0. So if you make the code like `enumerate(infile, start=1)` you won't need to add 1 to idx anymore

Comment: @Olivier Thanks. That's a great point. I was not aware of that. I have updated the answer.